# Fontello - how to add fonts to existing project?

Tags: css, icons, fontello

How can I add more fonts to an existing Fontello directory?

I know I can re-import my config.json into the Fontello website, then select new fonts, then re-download the config file.

This updates the config file but not, of course, the actual .css files.

So short of downloading the entire ZIP again (which is annoying as it has a different random suffix in the filename each time), how can this be done?

I've also tried via CLI but there's [basically no documentation](https://github.com/paulyoung/fontello-cli) on how this might be achieved, if it even can.

```
cd /path/to/my/fontello/dir
npm run-script build
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some more digging I found a few ways to do this. My preference was from CLI. Although the Fontello-CLI docs on Github are bare, Fontello's own docs discuss updating projects via CLI.

[Install](https://www.npmjs.com/) the Node package manager (NPM)

1. Open a command line interface (CMD)
2. Install the Fontello-CLI via `npm install fontello-cli -g`
3. `cd` to the directory your Fontello folder lives in - NOT the directory itself
4. Run `fontello-cli --config <fontello-dir-name>/config.json open` to open your project on the Fontello website. Your project's existing fonts will already be selected. You can now add more fonts.
5. When done, go back to CMD and run `fontello-cli --config {fontello-dir-name}/config.json install` - this will update your project with the revised choices.

Voila!

Comment: One additional step required for me on Mac OS was `fontello-cli open {path/}config.json` to actually open the session on the site.

Comment: You're a legend, thank you!